# spf13/cobra can't download binary to $GOPATH/bin

Tags: go, gopath, go-cobra

I want to use spf13/cobra on my project.

[spf13/cobra: A Commander for modern Go CLI interactions](https://github.com/spf13/cobra)

typed install command result

```
$ go get -u github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra
go: downloading github.com/spf13/cobra v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra v0.0.0-20200826151851-02a0d2fbc9e6
go: github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra upgrade => v0.0.0-20200826151851-02a0d2fbc9e6
go get github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra: ambiguous import: found package github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra in multiple modules:
        github.com/spf13/cobra v1.0.0 (/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.0.0/cobra)
        github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra v0.0.0-20200826151851-02a0d2fbc9e6 (/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra@v0.0.0-20200826151851-02a0d2fbc9e6)
```

but not found `cobra` command and binary file.

```
$ cobra
bash: cobra: command not found
$ ls -la $GOPATH/bin | grep cobra
// not found binary
```

this is my go env.

```
$ go env
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/vscode/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/vscode/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/workspaces/[my-package-name]/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build068490139=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

and develop via container based on [microsoft/vscode-remote-try-go](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-try-go).

How can I do install binary to `$GOPATH/bin`?

Comment: set version `go get -u github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra@v1.0.0` and works correctly

Answer (score 3):

Install the Cobra Generator

```
go get github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra
```

More Info: https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/master/cobra/README.md

Comment: Update: now the command is 
"go install github.com/spf13/cobra-cli@latest"
And the link is https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

Actually `go get -u github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra` will install `cobra` into `$GOPATH/bin/cobra` you can check it by:

```
ls $GOPATH/bin/cobra
```

But when you run:

```
cobra
```

in your environment must be specified `$PATH` which leads to `$GOPATH/bin`, to do that you must run:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

So now all must be ok.

PS: Add `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` to your `~/.bash_profile` file so it will work after terminal restart.

Answer (score 0):

for those who face this problems

you need to instal the **cobra-cli** NOT **cobra**

```
go install github.com/spf13/cobra-cli@latest
```

dont install with command like following

```
go get -u github.com/spf13/cobra@latest
```